# @EJB annotation vs JNDI lookup + transaction

Tags: jpa, java-native-interface, ejb, geronimo

Acording to another post [1] there's no difference between invoking a session EJB via JNDI lookup and using the @EJB annotation. However, in the following scenario:

1.- call session EJB1(JDBC inserts here)
2.- From EJB1, call session EJB2 (more inserts here)
3.- Rollback the transaction (from EJB1)

If I use the @EJB annotation it works fine, but with the JNDI lookup it doesn´t, the transaction in the second EJB is a new one and the rollback doesn´t happen. All this with CMT.

I'm deploying all this stuff in a Geronimo/ibmwasce-2.1.1.6.

¿Do I need to pass the transaction from one EJB to another explicitly? I thought it was the continer job. ¿Any clues?

[1] [@EJB annotation vs JNDI lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681436/ejb-annotation-vs-jndi-lookup)

Update:

Code via annotation:

```
@EJB
private CodAppEjb codAppejbAnotacion;
```

Code via jndi:

```
CodAppEjb codAppejb;
InitialContext ctx;
Properties properties= new Properties();
properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "ejbd://127.0.0.1:4201");
properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
codAppejb= (CodAppEjb) ctx.lookup("CodAppEjbBeanRemote");
```

The transaction code is just the same.

Comment: Transaction behavior should not vary based on lookup vs injection. I recommend including the code snippets that work and don't work. I must also point out that stateful session beans are an example where injection and JNDI vary, since JNDI must be used as the "factory".

Comment: Ok, I've updated the post with the code snippets, thank you bkail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, you have a transaction propagation problem.

The problem seems to be, that in your `JNDI` lookup you search for the **remote EJB** (not Local), which does **NOT** get executed in the same transaction context as EJB1.

When using the `@EJB` annotation above, the local implementation is injected, with the same transaction context.

Comment: This post confirms this behavior: http://blog.pwsindonesia.com/index.php/2011/06/07/how_to_call_geronimo_2_2_local_ejb_using